# Connect to Elasticsearch in a Fastify app with username and password via @fastify/elasticsearch package

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, fastify

I'm a new Fastify user. I created a `fastify@4.0.0` app via `fastify-cli`. I want to connect to Elasticsearch via username and password, but in the `@fastify/elasticsearch` documentation there is no mention of it. As the documentation said:

```
const fastify = require('fastify')()

fastify.register(require('@fastify/elasticsearch'), { node: 'http://xxxx:9200' })

fastify.get('/user', async function (req, reply) {
  const { body } = await this.elastic.search({
    index: 'tweets',
    body: {
      query: { match: { text: req.query.q }}
    }
  })

  return body.hits.hits
})

fastify.listen({ port: 3000 }, err => {
  if (err) throw err
});
```

I don't know how to set a username and password to connect to my Elasticsearch instance. Is it true?

```
fastify.register(require('@fastify/elasticsearch'), { node: 'http://8.8.8.8:9200', username: 'xxxx', password: 'xxxx' });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it. Just follow this pattern `<protocol>://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>`.

```
fastify.register(require('@fastify/elasticsearch'), { node: 'http://xxxx:xxxx@8.8.8.8:9200' });
```